# Batch running multiple Newman (Postman) test collections

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner

I have defined several Postman test collections/folders and their associated test data files. Running them through Postman Collection Runner and Newman individually works fine. I wanted to batch multiple runs together, like this .bat in Windows:

```
SET postman_collection=Regression.postman_collection.json
SET postman_environment=Development.postman_environment.json

SET postman_folder="Order details"
SET postman_data="orders.json"
newman run %postman_collection% -r html,cli -e %postman_environment% --folder %postman_folder% -d %postman_data%

SET postman_folder="Fuzzy Search"
SET postman_data="fuzzy search regression.csv"
newman run %postman_collection% -r html,cli -e %postman_environment% --folder %postman_folder% -d %postman_data%

SET postman_folder="Sorting"
SET postman_data=""
newman run %postman_collection% -r html,cli -e %postman_environment% --folder %postman_folder% -d %postman_data%
```

However, execution ends after the first newman run completes. I think it terminates the console for some reason.

How can I achieve what I want to do above? Am I structuring my tests incorrectly? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have u tried doing the same from a js file and running the js in a node?

Comment: I am in the process of trying this now. I was hoping that I could just throw a quick batch file together. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You just have to use "call" before newman command as follows:

```
SET postman_collection=Regression.postman_collection.json
SET postman_environment=Development.postman_environment.json

SET postman_folder="Order details"
SET postman_data="orders.json"

call newman run %postman_collection% -r html,cli -e %postman_environment% --folder %postman_folder% -d %postman_data%

SET postman_folder="Fuzzy Search"
SET postman_data="fuzzy search regression.csv"

call newman run %postman_collection% -r html,cli -e %postman_environment% --folder %postman_folder% -d %postman_data%
```